# Jquery Sortable Auto Sort

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

can we sort the jquery sortable at runtime using the id or idx as taken by me in each li. I want it to sort in the run time

[here is fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rigids/wmaqb/) . I want it to auto sort for eg `<li id=1>` should come first than `<li id=2>` and so on.. Help will be appreciated as I am Novice trying to learn jquery.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="demo" style="width:444px">

<ul id="sortable">
   <li itemID=3 id='3' class="ui-state-default">3<button>delete</button></li>
    <li itemID=6 id='6' class="ui-state-default">6<button>delete</button></li>

    <li itemID=1 id='1' class="ui-state-default">1<button>delete</button></li>
    <li itemID=4 id='4' class="ui-state-default">4<button>delete</button></li>
    <li itemID=9 id='9' class="ui-state-default">9<button>delete</button></li>
    <li itemID=2 id='2' class="ui-state-default">2<button>delete</button></li>
    <li itemID=8 id='8' class="ui-state-default">8<button>delete</button></li>
    <li itemID=5 id='5' class="ui-state-default">5<button>delete</button></li>
    <li itemID=11 id='11' class="ui-state-default">11<button>delete</button></li>
    <li itemID=7 id='7' class="ui-state-default">7<button>delete</button></li>
    <li itemID=10 id='10' class="ui-state-default">10<button>delete</button></li>

    <li  itemID=12 id='12' class="ui-state-default">12<button>delete</button></li>

</ul>

</div><!-- End demo -->
```

Here's the JS:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable();

    $(":button").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
    var arr=$("#sortable").sortable('toArray');
    text=arr.toString();
    alert(text);
    });

});
```

And here's the CSS:

```
#sortable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#sortable li { margin: 3px 3px 3px 0; padding: 1px; float: left; width: 100px; height: 90px; font-size: 4em; text-align: center; }
```

I also pull in a bunch of libraries and CSS (not sure if it is required on JSFiddle or not):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jqueryui.com/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css">
<script src="http://jqueryui.com/jquery-1.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script src="http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>

<script src="http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.mouse.js"></script>
<script src="http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.sortable.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jqueryui.com/demos/demos.css">
```

Comment: Added code to question to keep it self-contained and searchable.  When other sites go down, SO questions must still be useful :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Check this out

http://jsfiddle.net/wmaqb/2/

Using the standard jQuery library and the `.sort()` method you can specify a function to use for sorting your array of objects.

```
$('#sort').click(function() {
    var mylist = $('#sortable');
    var listitems = mylist.children('li').get();
    listitems.sort(function(a, b) {
        var compA = parseFloat($(a).attr('id'));
        var compB = parseFloat($(b).attr('id'));
        return (compA < compB) ? -1 : (compA > compB) ? 1 : 0;
    });        
    $.each(listitems, function(idx, itm) {
        mylist.append(itm);
    });
});
```

Once you got this array sorted, you can simply order them with a `.each()` cycle