# Quicksand alternative

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Anyone who know a alternative to this?

http://razorjack.net/quicksand/

Maybe something that would actually sort auto? (Yes i'm lazy, k?)

EDIT:

By auto I mean, it should just sort, after some tags etc `data-name="derr"` (find anyone with id derr), not have 2 different divs...

And maybe sort after more things at once...
I kinda have to do this, because, the user is suposed to choose from 0 to 4 different tags...
Don't want to make all the possibilities in html D:

Comment: If you've got a pretty functional thing here... why are you looking elsewhere? Please put more effort in the question. Sort auto is a conceptual sort. What's auto? Automatic? Sort automatic? Why don't you present the information already sorted server-side?

Comment: Checkout those two links : - http://masonry.desandro.com/ (free)
- http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/28-high-quality-jquery-plugins-for-building-responsive-websites/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't seen anything in the wild anything that does what **Quicksand** does, as Quicksand created something entirely new.

They do have an example, complete with **source code** to allow sorting of the filtered results [HERE](http://razorjack.net/quicksand/demos/one-set-clone.html). Just take a look at the example and notice you can inject a fixed value instead of reading the results of the radio button. That will take care of your **auto-sorting** requirements.

If that method of sorting is not needed, using **jQuery .sort()** can also be done as shown in this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6303737/1195891) after your results have been filtered by Quicksand and prior to them being animated/displayed.

As far as "***sort after more things at once***", Quicksand will read your tags that you have per-defined with **filter categories** which can be more than one type, but since you don't want to do that via HTML I have to assume is because you are viewing ALL categories from the start.

That said, just configure Quicksand to show **nothing** from the start and as the user adds **0 to 4 different tags** the filtered results are then "**auto-sorted**" and will always reflect the user defined tags provided.

How to configure Quicksand to **show nothing** from the start? Make a **category** that has no filtered-matches will allow this to happen. That particular category can also be hidden from the menu too.

Comment: Hmm, havn't seen that, but still, I have to sort out about 4 different tags.. D: I think I'm gonna make my own thing D:

Comment: I highly recommend this [tutorial with live demo](http://tutorialzine.com/2011/06/beautiful-portfolio-html5-jquery/) that shows an excellent method to use the Quicksand plugin. If you take a look at the comments below, you will see a few posts by me with tips including **html** and **.js** examples to use with **Shadowbox**, a lightbox alternative. Also, you can have clickable links in the navigation too.

Comment: Awesome, I've been looking for that tut quite a while now :D But then again, I need something, so that you can filter with more than one tag right now... :/

Comment: The Quicksand filter isn't limited to a single filter, it can have multiple filters via comma separated names.

Answer (score 5):

We used Isotope on our company website - it's a dynamic layout engine with similar functionality.
It supports filtering and sorting:

http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

Note that there is a $25 one-time license fee for commercial use - but it's a lot cheaper than having to write something yourself.

Comment: @Mobilpadde "The open source license is designed for you to use Isotope to build open source and personal projects. The Isotope open source license is GPLv3... The commercial license is designed to for you to use Isotope in commercial products and applications, without the provisions of the GPLv3"